# how to train a vgg16 model more efficiently with a custom dataset

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, anaconda, vgg-net

i have implemented a **VGG16** model from scratch with all its layer. when i trained it with my custom image data set, it takes 5 hours to complete 1 epoch and is time consuming. i just stopped it there.

how can i train my model a bit more faster because my data set is very unique. is there a way to simply my task of training so that i can get a good accuracy .

my **dataset** has 5 classes for training with 3000 colored images each and 1000 colored images each for validation in 2 separate folders of validation and training. i am using **Keras** to build my **VGG16** model.

Comment: why "from scratch"? why don't you use the pre-trained weights? vgg-16 has been trained with insane GPUs, probably for days/weeks, of course it's slow.

Comment: will this pretrained model be used to train with my custom dataset?

Comment: You can add your own Dense layers on top so yes

Comment: can you send me a resource link where i can follow the tutorial about this. it would be very helpful from you. thanks in advanced

Comment: look at this : https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html 

In the "Finetuning the convnet" section - replace resnet with vgg.
You can choose to freeze the pretrained weights (this is called transfer learning) or continue training them from the initial pretrained weights (this is called fine tuning).